# Error when running migration on sequelize

Tags: postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
 up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  return Promise.all([
   queryInterface.addColumn('Posts', 'userAccountId', {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   }),
   queryInterface.addColumn('Posts', 'postTopicId', {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   }),
   queryInterface.addConstraint('Posts', ['userAccountId'], {
    type: 'foreign key',
    name: 'userAccountId',
    references: {
     table: 'UserAccounts',
     field: 'id',
    },
    onDelete: 'no action',
    onUpdate: 'no action',
   }),
   queryInterface.addConstraint('Posts', ['postTopicId'], {
    type: 'foreign key',
    name: 'postTopicId',
    references: {
     table: 'PostTopics',
     field: 'id',
    },
    onDelete: 'no action',
    onUpdate: 'no action',
   }),
  ]);
 },

 down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  return Promise.all([
   queryInterface.removeColumn('Posts', 'userAccountId'),
   queryInterface.removeColumn('Posts', 'postTopicId'),
   queryInterface.removeConstraint('Posts', 'userAccountId'),
   queryInterface.removeConstraint('Posts', 'postTopicId'),
  ]);
 },
};
```

When I run the command npx sequelize db:migrate, I receive this error "ERROR: column "postTopicId" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist"

I dont what is wrong, all the other migrations running ok.
I'm running my database in a docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `Promise.all` while executing queries that modifying structure and depending on each other. `Promise.all` does not guarantee an original order of execution queries. Use transaction and sequential execution:

```
return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
            await queryInterface.addColumn('Posts', 'userAccountId', {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            }, { transaction })
            await queryInterface.addColumn('Posts', 'postTopicId', {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            }, { transaction })
            await queryInterface.addConstraint('Posts', ['userAccountId'], {
                type: 'foreign key',
                name: 'userAccountId',
                references: {
                    table: 'UserAccounts',
                    field: 'id',
                },
                onDelete: 'no action',
                onUpdate: 'no action',
            }, { transaction })
            await queryInterface.addConstraint('Posts', ['postTopicId'], {
                type: 'foreign key',
                name: 'postTopicId',
                references: {
                    table: 'PostTopics',
                    field: 'id',
                },
                onDelete: 'no action',
                onUpdate: 'no action',
            }, { transaction })
        });
```